# Are there any successors of Lost?

Tags: lost

I'm currently watching again the series. I just love it. But as the end is pretty pathetic, and I heard even the writers only ended it because there wasn’t any money for a new series, I started to wonder:

**Is there any successor to Lost?**

This may include:

- books
- films
- series (maybe they just renamed it for copyright issues?)
- background literature (like the *Silmarillion of the Island*)
- (video) games

Canon would be preferred, but fan-made stories would also fit.

I know that video games have been made, but I haven't looked into them. Maybe one of your answers can tell if they just re-tell the story or if they provide more information.

Comment: “even the writers meant that this has been only made because they had to” — I’m not clear what this sentence means.

Comment: (And I think we all just quietly agreed to pretend that Lost never happened.)

Comment: Well the creators stated that the ending has been made because they didn't have money to do another season. So maybe they have made up the story in games or something. :)

Comment: ah okay. I thought they announced that they’d only do six seasons like three years in advance, and that that was because the producers didn’t want it to run any longer: http://variety.com/2007/scene/markets-festivals/lost-set-for-three-more-years-1117964371/ Have you got a source that contradicts that?

Comment: I recalled that the ending has been a last-minute decision. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Sure looks like it! (Do you mean the actual ending they produced wasn’t quite what they wanted to do, due to budget limitations?)

Comment: Well it just feels that the show has been cut off, as the only thing that has been solved is the personal issues from the Lostie's. But every other question or riddle in the show has been left unanswered. That's why I look for successors. :D

Comment: “every other question or riddle in the show has been left unanswered” — I don’t think that’s quite true. Try watching it again. Maybe make some notes.

Comment: It is true. Sorry, that not EVERY question hasn't been answered, but many of them. What's with the Tawaret statue? What exactly is the core/light of the island? What are the rules of the island? Why is birth so complicated? There are many other examples. That's why I want to know more about it outside of the series.

Comment: Every question answered will simply lead to another question. You should rest. Just be grateful you're alive.

Comment: You mean I haven't been dead since the beginning of the series?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23728/discussion-between-paul-d-waite-and-trollwut).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: You are right. They knew three years in advance that it will end after six seasons. This deal was a special wish of the producers, so that they won't need last minute changes.

Comment: There's no successor but there is a precursor called Gilligan's Island...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were a handful of Alternate Reality Games.

- [The Lost Experience](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Experience)
- [Find 815](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Find_815)
- [Dharma Initiative Recruiting Project](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Dharma_Initiative_Recruiting_Project)
- [Lost University](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_University)
- [Damon, Carlton, and a Polar Bear](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Damon,_Carlton_and_a_Polar_Bear)

The following were tie-in books.

- [Endangered Species](http://lost.wikia.com/wiki/Endangered_Species)
- [Secret Identity](http://lost.wikia.com/wiki/Secret_Identity)
- [Signs of Life](http://lost.wikia.com/wiki/Signs_of_Life)
- [Bad Twin](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Bad_Twin)

There was also a companion book.

- [The Lost Chronicles: The Official Companion Book](http://lost.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Chronicles:_The_Official_Companion_Book)

There was one non-ARG video game.

- [Via Domus](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Lost:_Via_Domus)

There was one special epilogue episode included on the Season 6 box set and the Complete Series set. It is the only content dealing with the time set *after* the main TV series.

- [The New Man In Charge](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Man_in_Charge)

With the exception of *The New Man In Charge*, all of this content was produced and released *during* the production of LOST. Nothing new has been created or released since the end of the show.

Comment: There was a Lost video game: Via Domus.

Comment: @RyanVeeder Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget the "deleted" scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sFnXe9eIFM

Comment: Don't forget the epilogue episode, [The New Man In Charge](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Man_in_Charge)

Comment: Namaste. Thats a nice answer! Thanks!